# Namespace declaration statement in laravel 5.4

Tags: namespaces, laravel-5.4

When I Want To Access my login route  then it threw me and error like this

> (1/1) FatalErrorException
>   Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script
>   in User.php (line 3)

but the Namespace of the UserController set Default by laravel

Here is the defined user controller namespace

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
```

Comment: is this your controller or your model? I think you mixed them up, the code you posted looks like a model to me

Comment: The problem has been solved. thanks for your response